# Specify input file encoding in UIMA Ruta Workbench

Tags: uima, ruta

I am experimenting with the ExampleProject available from Apache UIMA Ruta and I would like to test the rules with some files of my own. Initially, I was getting an exception, which I believe was due to UIMA not being able to detect the encoding of the input files. After converting the input files to UTF-8, I no longer get the exception. However, I am not sure whether Ruta is correctly reading the files.

How can I specify the encoding of the input files when using the UIMA Ruta Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the encoding specified in the Eclipse project is utilized for reading the input files and the descriptors. However, there is a bug (version 2.5.0) that prevents this. Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to set the utilized encoding. The encoding will always be the default encoding: UTF-8

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*